# Can a client consume both a WCF and a RIA Services endpoint?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I need to configure end-points on my Silverlight client for both a WCF and a RIA Services endpoint. Is this possible? If so, what are the gotchas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the one thing I could say is that there is some overlapping between both anyway, in fact RIA is already using WCF but just creates another layer to work easier with SOAP and JSON (good because silverlight runs in the client and those data structures are natural for small transferences), as long as your services are basic enough you might work with any of them.

But the overall need for RIA was that Silverlight cannot make 'intrusive' tasks like updating a database, so there was a need to create a lightweight service infrastructure to help you make those tasks.

If you ever think that a RIA service contract might also be useful for other clients, maybe you will gain something by porting it to the normal WCF platform which will give you a lot more flexibility and reliability.

I hope this adds something to the discussion,

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my client working with both endpoints. I troubles I had had nothing to do with there being two types of endpoints, though I thought they did. If anyone has anything to add about gotchas, I'll accept their answer, otherwise I think the answer is a resounding yes. I figured it was since RIA Services is fundamentally WCF anyway.

Comment: Absolutely. WCF Ria Services IS WCF. No doubt. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh/archive/2009/11/23/understanding-the-wcf-in-wcf-ria-services.aspx.
Regarding your scenario it's quite common, I don't believe you'll encounter any particular problem